# How to simplify this code? [Python DEF + LOOP]

Tags: python, function, loops

How to simplify this code?
It works, but sometimes it gives me an error:
*"Fatal Python error: _Py_CheckRecursiveCall: Cannot recover from stack overflow. Python runtime state: initialized"*

```
def restart():
 task_counter = 0

 def open_task(task_counter):
   if task_counter != 21:
    try:
        task_counter += 1 
        print(task_counter)
        time.sleep(1)
        open_task(task_counter)
    except:
        open_task(task_counter)
   if task_counter == 21:
    time.sleep(2)
    restart()

 open_task(task_counter)

restart()
```

i need exactly this part to be simplified:
this part must work like loop.

```
def open_task(task_counter):
       if task_counter != 21:
        try:
            task_counter += 1 
            print(task_counter)
            time.sleep(1)
            open_task(task_counter)
        except:
            open_task(task_counter)
       if task_counter == 21:
        time.sleep(2)
        restart()
    
open_task(task_counter)
```

Comment: DON'T use recursion for things like this.  Use a `while True:` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that every recursive call takes up memory for the stack frame.  It has to allocate and maintain a new namespace for each new invocations.  Some languages are able to detect "tail recursion", which is what you are doing, and will turn it into a "jump" instead of a "call".  Python doesn't do that.

So, just use `while` loops.

```
def restart():

    def open_task(task_counter):
        while task_counter < 21:
            try:
                task_counter += 1 
                print(task_counter)
                time.sleep(1)
            except:
                pass
        time.sleep(2)

    while True:
        task_counter = 0
        open_task(task_counter)

restart()
```

Comment: Of course, testing this will irritate you because it can't be killed -- the try/except catches your Ctrl-C.

Comment: Downvoters are entitled to their opinion.  It's probably because I did not provide an explanation of the code.  They're mostly right.